# CORS Pre-Flight fail only one method

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, cors

I have an extremely unusual issue that has just popped up. I’m writing an Ionic app with a ASP.NET Web API backend. I tackled the pre-flight CORS issues early on, by adding this to the register method of my WebApiConfig class:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

When navigating each page, and making various $http.get calls, the pre-flight CORS is working a treat (below is network traffic taken from Chrome Developer Tools)

[image: Example 1]

However I have recently created an additional method in WebApi:

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/GetJobType")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetJobType(int? id)
    {
        var model = new JobsModel();
        return this.Ok(model.GetJobType(id.Value));
    }
```

But the pre-flight OPTIONS request is returning a 404:

[image]

This is the $http.get code:

```
    var url = ApiEndpoint.url + '/GetJobType/' + jobId;
    $http.get(url).then(function(resp) {
        alert(resp.data);

    }, function(err) {
        alert(err);
    });
```

Any ideas why the OPTIONS request would fail for only one method, while the rest work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the pre-flight request, it's your route. You are getting a 404 which means it cannot find the requested resource. Add your parameter to the route.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet, Route("api/GetJobType/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetJobType(int? id)
{
   try
   {
     var model = new JobsModel();
     return Ok(model.GetJobType(id.Value));
   }
   catch
   {
     return InternalServerError();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Stephen, it seems to work now which is super weird as none of my other HTTPGet methods that pass parameters have needed to have the parameter reflected in the route attribute like that. Thanks anyway :)